# Date in Playframework

Tags: date, jpa, playframework

I have Model which has Date information:

```
package models;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

import play.data.binding.As;
import play.db.jpa.*;
@Entity
public class testing extends Model {
…
public  Date date;
// I even tried public @As("yyyy-MM-dd") Date date;

…
public test1 {…date…}
}
```

Then I have a controller which receive user submitted date (and other information), save to database

```
public static void post(… @As("yyyy-MM-dd") Date date, …) {
}
```

Others information work well, I can save them all in database except date. After running, all information are posted to MySql but Date field was still Null

Debug information for date in controller is as follow:
Nov 7, 2011 12:00:00 AM
So I think that it might be conflict in type of controller and model. But how?
Please help me.

Comment: Can you post the code from your controller where you place the date on at persisted class and save it? I guess you're missing something there, because as you say, the date is available in your controller..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using Play 1.2.3 / 1.2.4-RC2,

It handles the date posting correctly, but I have made 2 little adjustments:

1) Add `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` before the date declaration. Without it the date is a time stamp (date including time), but I think that is not the issue:

```
...
@Entity
public class Testing extends Model {
  ...
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  public Date date;
  ...
}
```

2) In the application.conf I've configuired the date format for all my locales

```
...
# Date format
# ~~~~~
date.format=yyyy-MM-dd
date.format.it=dd/MM/yyyy
date.format.en=MM/dd/yyyy
date.format.fr=dd/MM/yyyy
#
```

Play posts dates correctly and mainly correctly validates parameters (ex. Long/Integer/Float/Double/BigDecimal/Date) based on current locale.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The As annotation in the controller is here to tell Play how to convert your request param into a Date.

After that you have an instance of Date and you don't have to worry about the format in the model.

Try to see in your controller what is the value of "request.params.get("date"). It is not in the format as you put in your As annotation then Play is not able to convert the string into Date.

I think this is your problem. So you have to change your view to post the right String or to change your As annotation to provide the right format according to the String you get

Comment: The request.params.get("date") returns 2011-11-07 (same with my variable); while using (@As("yyyy-MM-dd") Date date), the variable date return to Nov 7, 2011 12:00:00 AM and I think this is the correct date type.

Comment: So everything is ok "Nov 7, 2011 12:00:00 AM" is just the toString for your variable date, your date is ok

Comment: Thank Seb Cesbron. Although the controller has handle the date correctly using As annotation, it still can not be updated to database while other field (string, double) does. I don't know what happen with this?